# How to use navigate back in for each loop?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I want to click on an element inside a list and go to different page. In this page I m taking a string. Then I go back and do the same for others. But after one iteration my code can't find the second element and shuts down the browser. Am I using the navigator wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public MainPage ControlSorting() {

    List <WebElement> listItems=driver.findElement(RESULTCONT).findElements(MEDIA);
    String[] strImdb = new String[listItems.size()];

    int l = 0;
    for (WebElement ele1 : listItems) {

            ele1.click();
            WebElement element   = getElementBy(ABOUTIMDB);
            String a=  element.getAttribute("ng-genre-action");
            String[] parts = a.split(",");
            strImdb[l]=parts[1];
            l++;

        driver.navigate().back();
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: How many items in `listItems`?
After `driver.navigate().back();` does the browser go back to main page?

Comment: 54. And yes it s going back but not clicking the second element @TuyenNguyen

Comment: Any exeception?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException @TuyenNguyen

Comment: Can you show the full log exeception? This exeception is hard to find out the reason. I think that when you go back, you need to find you element again

Comment: Well yes you re right. Thx for the answer :) @TuyenNguyen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back you have to re identify the object. Please add the following code inside for loop at the first line of your code.

```
listItems=driver.findElement(RESULTCONT).findElements(MEDIA);
```

This should work. Please try and let me know.